# Adding a role to a user when they click a reaction on a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am setting up a new entry system for my Discord server with my bot, but I am having a hang up on getting some code to function.

My basic goal, is to have a post sitting in the welcome channel with rules and info, and the user has to click a reaction on the post, then the bot gives them a specific role and removes the 'Newbie' role. I have no had any issues doing this as long as the user is the one calling the message, but my issue comes in when trying to pull the guildMember object in, so I can roles.add them, it just doesn't seem to work? I've tried several different methods and have came up short every time. :C

message_id is being identified and ran properly, I am console logging and caching it outside of this block, seems fine. It's just this part that I cannot get to work. The bot doesn't error, or reply to the event.

Using node.js 12 (dino is my Client, btw)

```
    dino.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.id == '☑️' && reaction.message.id === message_id) {
        let ourUser = reaction.message.guild.member(user)
        ourUser.roles.add(`add ID would go here`)
        ourUser.roles.remove(`Remove ID would go here`)
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: "The bot doesn't error, or reply to the event." 

I do not oddly.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I was calling emoji.id instead of emoji.name lol. I'm an idiot. Works fine now, soon as I post it, I figure it out.. ofc.